# Issue with drawable folder for 540 * 960 , Unable to view the actual size in emulator

Tags: android, android-layout, drawable

I have created a drawable folder for 540 * 960 size as name like `drawable-sw540` and also created `layout-sw540`,but running in emulator resolution of 540 * 960.It doesn't effect and view the actual drawable and getting from default drawable and layout.
If anyone have idea about this please reply.

Answer (score 1):

The Resolution is specified in pixels i.e. 540 * 960 pixels.
But in Android, resource folders are specified in **Density-independent Pixels(dp)** not **pixels(px)**. So `drawable-sw540` may not be the correct folder.
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-of-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android) for more info

First calculate the *dp* of your device and then name layouts and drawables according to that.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by trying following steps:-
1. add new xml layout and set custom configuration like dimension,density etc.So create a new drawable folder of the defined configuration,then i put all the drawable images to that folder. 
2.Created custom AVD of the required configuration(540*960) and run application in emulator.
so finally it works fine.........